# Notify that a user is already performing edit on this object

Tags: java, spring-boot, locking

This is more of a design question.

#### The background

I'm working on a 'small' Spring Boot webapp fed via PostgreSQL DB that would enhance my teams ability to test out new patches for a particular application. Each patch will generate a series of tests that need to be performed on specific servers. These servers are distributed on few geographical regions that have separate teams that need to perform these tests in order to have a sign-off that the patch is stable. The teams consist of few team members.

#### The problem

The idea is that when one team member is starting a particular test, a 'lock' is created, for example for 15 minutes, on that object, and when other users try to issue the test, they will get a notification -> User XYZ is already performing this test. To prevent unnecessary work and also a double test data inputs that would collide with each other.

I was tinkering with a custom built mechanism that would have a separate table that would have a info about the object, user that created the lock and the lock expiration time. So when a user pick up a test and a webform is presented to fill in the details, two things occur:

1. The entry in the locking table is created for that object
2. A cookie is set in the users browser local storage that a javascript function is checking every n seconds and later pops up a warning that the lease for the object is about to expire -> Do You want to extent the lease ? Yes/No.

There is also the problem of releasing the lock manually and also extending the lock(I guess a REST API endpoint to perform these operations is simple enough), but I guess this would create a big portion of logic that needs to be driven very manually on the server side that I want to avoid.

The problem here is that I can work this out and make it work, but I do not want to re-invent the wheel and maybe there is already a more standarized way of doing this. There is also the problem of maintenance for something that is completely custom built and I'm pretty sure that this would become a big monster of itself very fast.

I was googling for quite some time now, but it seems that I'm not using the correct keywords. All the results point me to the Spring JPA locking mechanism, but I'm pretty sure this will not get me where I want to go with this.

All info and remarks welcome. I'm not looking for a finished solution, but more like a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: A separate Redis server?

Comment: Could the test environments be replicated? Or dockerized for testing?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Simplest answer is no. The topic is broad in terms of why that is so and it's just not a factor here.(could write a novel about this process) Let's just leave it in terms - the testing is done by humans in different regions and this process piece is not wanted to be automated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock  we use it for making sure 2 scheduled processes don't run at the same time, but you might be able to either use portions of it or get inspired by it for how to write your own.

It basically adds an entry in a db table (you can choose different persistence mechanisms) and prevents other threads or servers from obtaining the same lock at the same time.  It also has a concept of a minimum lock time and max lock time which are important and that you'll want to implement if doing it yourself.